# JSPRIT - outputting the best solution as JSON to a string

Tags: java, json, jsprit

I've written JSPRIT into a Jersey 2 RESTful server. I want our apps to call the server (POST) with a JSON string of a problem, feed the JSON request to JSPRIT and then output the best solution as JSON.

Everything works great.... except. I cannot work out how to output the solution to a JSON string. All the examples use VrpXMLWriter that writes to a disk file. I want to write the output as JSON to a string - not a file.

I've spent a few hours with my friend Google but have not worked it out.

Can someone help please ?

Comment: You'll have to get to grips with building JSON in Java, the question is too broad to answer properly. However, have a look in `SolutionPrinter.java` which will give you an indication of how to obtain all of the data points

Comment: Sometimes the simplest advice is the best. Thanks roganjosh. SolutionPrinter gave me everything I needed to work it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old question, but hopefully the below solution can help someone:

```
import java.io.OutputStream;
import org.json.XML;

OutputStream xmlOutputStream = new VrpXMLWriter(problem, solutions, true).write();
String xmlOutput = xmlOutputStream.toString();
String jsonOutput = XML.toJSONObject(xmlOutput).toString();
```